Plane geometry problem involving a square with its sides bisected by line segments that divide the square into four quadrilaterals
Update: I recently proved a result involving the combined areas of quadrilaterals opposite to each other in this type of problem. For the details, see my answer below.
The result applied in the case of this specific problem simplifies the problem to solving $32+16=20+x \implies x=28$


I encountered a plane geometry problem which had a picture like the above square and which provided the following information:
Each of the 4 line segments inside the square has one of its endpoints at the midpoint of one of the sides of the square and its other endpoint at a point that is common to the 4 line segments.
The problem gives you only the $3$ areas corresponding to each of three quadrilateral regions, and asks you to solve for the area of the fourth quadrilateral region. You are not told the total area enclosed by the square. You are also not told the side length of the square.
The area of the Northeast quadrilateral is $32$
The area of the Northwest quadrilateral is $20$
The area of the Southwest quadrilateral is $16$
The problem is to find the area of the Southeast quadrilateral.

Consider the square of side length $2s$ and area $4s^2$ with vertices
$$
\text{NE}=(s,s),
\;\;\;
\text{NW}=(-s,s),
\;\;\;
\text{SW}=(-s,-s),
\;\;\;
\text{SE}=(s,-s)
$$
and edge midpoints
$$
\text{E}=(s,0),
\;\;\;
\text{N}=(0,s),
\;\;\;
\text{W}=(-s,0),
\;\;\;
\text{S}=(0,-s)
$$
Let $\text{C}=(a,b)$ be an interior point of the square.

Let quadrilaterals
$Q_1,Q_2,Q_3,Q_4$
have consecutive vertices as shown below
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|}
&\text{vertices}\\
\hline
Q_1&\text{C},\;\text{E},\;\text{NE},\;\text{N}\\
\hline
Q_2&\text{C},\;\text{N},\;\text{NW},\;\text{W}\,\\
\hline
Q_3&\text{C},\;\text{W},\;\text{SW},\;\text{S}\\
\hline
Q_4&\text{C},\;\text{S},\;\text{SE},\;\text{E}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
and let $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$ be the areas of $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3,Q_4$, respectively.

Our main goal is to find the value of $k_4$, assuming it's given that
$k_1=32,k_2=20,k_3=16$.

As an additional task, we'll find the values of $a,b$ so as to verify that the point $\text{C}=(a,b)$ is actually in the interior of the square.

Applying the shoelace formula

$\qquad$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

we get
\begin{align*}
-{\small{\frac{a}{2}}}s
+s^2
-{\small{\frac{b}{2}}}s
&=32
&&(\text{eq}1)
\\[4pt]
{\small{\frac{a}{2}}}s
+s^2
-{\small{\frac{b}{2}}}s
&=20
&&(\text{eq}2)
\\[4pt]
{\small{\frac{a}{2}}}s
+s^2
+{\small{\frac{b}{2}}}s
&=16
&&(\text{eq}3)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
From the sum
$(\text{eq}1)+(\text{eq}3)$,
we get
$2s^2=48$, hence $s=2\sqrt{6}$.

Replacing $s$ by $2\sqrt{6}$ in equations $(\text{eq}1),(\text{eq}2)$, respectively, we get
\begin{align*}
a+b&=-{\small{\frac{4}{3}}}\sqrt{6}\\[4pt]
a-b&=-{\small{\frac{2}{3}}}\sqrt{6}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which yields $a=-\sqrt{6}$ and $b=-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{6}$.

Then, noting that $|a| < s$ and $|b| < s$, it follows that the point $\text{C}=(a,b)$ is in the interior of the square.

Finally, we get
$$
k_4
=
4s^2-(k_1+k_2+k_3)
=
96-68
=
28
$$
which completes the analysis.

Another way to arrive at the $28$ value would be to use the fact that the sum of the areas of two quadrilaterals opposite to each other is the same as the sum of the other two quadrilaterals opposite to each other. I managed to prove this "opposite quadrilaterals" result a few moments ago, to my satisfaction. Now my only curiosity is with regards to why Heron's Formula (I divided each quadrilateral into a right triangle and a scalene triangle) led me astray. Any idea why Heron's Formula led me to the strange result that had me initially confused? What went wrong in applying Heron's formula?

By the "opposite quadrilaterals" result, this problem becomes as simple as solving $32+16=20+x \implies x=28$

@Simon M: As regards the "opposite quadrilaterals" result, if your proof is not too complicated, you might consider posting it as an alternate answer.

I'd be happy to. I'll get around to it soon. I'm also going to try to find out what went wrong in my use of Heron's Formula in my original attempt to solve the problem


Here, $s$ is half of the side length of the larger square.
I will prove that $$(A+\frac{s^2}{2})+(C+\frac{s^2}{2})=(B+\frac{s^2}{2})+(D+\frac{s^2}{2})$$ $\tag1$
By doing so, the problem will become as simple as $$(32)+(16)=(20)+D+\frac{1}{2}s^2 \implies D+\frac{1}{2}s^2=28$$
First, by the Pythagorean Theorem we know that:

$L_{1}=\sqrt{b^{2}+\left(s+a\right)^{2}}$
$L_{2}=\sqrt{a^{2}+\left(s+b\right)^{2}}$

Next, by Heron's Formula we know that

$A=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\left(s\sqrt{2}+L_{1}+L_{2}\right)\left(-s\sqrt{2}+L_{1}+L_{2}\right)\left(s\sqrt{2}-L_{1}+L_{2}\right)\left(s\sqrt{2}+L_{1}-L_{2}\right)}$

Since $s \in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$, this simplifies to $A=\frac{1}{2}(s^2+as+bs)$
Thus, $A+\frac{1}{2}s^2=s^2+\frac{1}{2}as+\frac{1}{2}bs$, which gives us the area of the quadrilateral region including $A$
Next, we can divide the quadrilateral region including $B$ and the quadrilateral region including $D$ each into a trapezoid and a right triangle.
Using the formula for the area of a trapezoid, we know that:

$B+\frac{1}{2}s^2=\frac{1}{2}[s+(s+b)](s-a)+\frac{1}{2}a(s+b)=s^2+\frac{1}{2}bs-\frac{1}{2}as$
$D+\frac{1}{2}s^2=\frac{1}{2}[s+(s+a)](s-b)+\frac{1}{2}b(s+a)=s^2+\frac{1}{2}as-\frac{1}{2}bs$

Next, we can divide the quadrilateral region including $C$ into a rectangle and two right triangles:

$C+\frac{1}{2}s^2=(s-a)(s-b)+\frac{1}{2}b(s-a)+\frac{1}{2}a(s-b)=s^2-\frac{1}{2}as-\frac{1}{2}bs$

Now, we can observe that $$(A+\frac{s^2}{2})+(C+\frac{s^2}{2})=2s^2=(B+\frac{s^2}{2})+(D+\frac{s^2}{2})$$
Now that we've proven (1), we can solve our problem as follows:
$$(32)+(16)=(20)+D+\frac{1}{2}s^2 \implies D+\frac{1}{2}s^2=28$$
Additionally, we can use $2s^2=48$ to conclude that $s=2\sqrt{6}$
Further, we can construct a system of equations using two of the area equations we derived along the way to show that $a=\sqrt{6}$ and $b=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{6}$
